# Will I miss app notifications if my iPhone doesn't have signal at that time

Tags: ios, iphone

If an app sends me a notification at 2pm and I was in place where there's no signal. After that when I went back to places with signal at 4pm, 
will I still receive that notification?
If so, is the notification time shows 2pm or 4pm?
Where are those notifications being queue up in this two hours?

Comment: They are queued on a push notification server so you'll receive it when you reconnect. It's super easy to test yourself. Put your phone in airplane mode, then do something to trigger a push notification (send yourself a Facebook message for example) then turn off airplane mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From APNS docs :

> Quality of Service
>
> Apple Push Notification service includes a default Quality of Service
>   (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs
>   attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the
>   notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered to
>   the device when it becomes available. Only one recent notification for
>   a particular app is stored. If multiple notifications are sent while
>   the device is offline, each new notification causes the prior
>   notification to be discarded. This behavior of keeping only the newest
>   notification is referred to as coalescing notifications. If the device
>   remains offline for a long time, any notifications that were being
>   stored for it are discarded.

The time that the notification is stored for seems to be not specified. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)